# Getting current display mode always null

Tags: java, swing, awt, fullscreen, retina-display

I'm trying to get the current display mode from the users video card so my game can be played in full screen. However, every time I look for a compatible display mode my method returns null which of course means I can't paint anything on the screen because theres nothing to paint to. So my question is how to fix this method so that it returns the appropriate display mode? I am on a Macbook Pro 15" Retina which leads me to believe it may be my computer. I printed the width and height of my screen:

```
 `Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();`
```

Which outputs 1440 width, 900 height. One of my compatible modes is 1440x900 so I'm not quite sure why it would not work. Here is the relevant code (bad mode gets printed every time):

```
//Find the first displaymode that is supported by the video card
public DisplayMode findFirstCompatibleDisplayMode(DisplayMode allDisplayModes[])
{
    DisplayMode goodDisplayModes[] = video_card.getDisplayModes();

    for (int i = 0; i < allDisplayModes.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < goodDisplayModes.length; j++)
            if (displayModesMatch(allDisplayModes[i], goodDisplayModes[j]))
            {
                System.out.println("good mode");
                return goodDisplayModes[j];
            }

    System.out.println("bad mode");
    return null;
}
```

The parameter allDisplayModes[] is initialized and passed through as this:

```
private static DisplayMode possibleDisplayModes[] = {
    new DisplayMode(1440, 900, 32, 0),
    new DisplayMode(1440, 900, 24, 0), new DisplayMode(1440, 900, 16, 0),
    new DisplayMode(800, 600, 24, 0), new DisplayMode(800, 600, 16, 0),
    new DisplayMode(640, 480, 32, 0), new DisplayMode(640, 480, 24, 0),
    new DisplayMode(640, 480, 16, 0)};
}
```

The displayModesMatch() method:

```
//Return trues when the video cards supported display mode is found
public boolean displayModesMatch(DisplayMode firstMode, DisplayMode secondMode)
{
    //Return true if both modes have the same resolution, bit depth, and refresh rate
    return firstMode.getWidth() == secondMode.getWidth() 
        && firstMode.getHeight() == secondMode.getHeight()
        && firstMode.getBitDepth() == secondMode.getBitDepth()
        && firstMode.getBitDepth() == DisplayMode.BIT_DEPTH_MULTI
        && secondMode.getBitDepth() == DisplayMode.BIT_DEPTH_MULTI
        && firstMode.getRefreshRate() == secondMode.getRefreshRate()
        && firstMode.getRefreshRate() == DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN
        && secondMode.getRefreshRate() == DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN;
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: `//Return trues when the video cards supported display mode is found`  No.. for that it would need `||` rather than `&&`..

Comment: If I did || then it would be true if ANY of the two properties are equal? Then it wouldn't necessarily mean they all matches... right?

Comment: I'll look at it more closely when there is a MCTaRE.

Comment: Theres not MCTaRE to show you, I've already shown it. We've found the source of the problem and now I simply want to know why it should be or not and...

Comment: *"I've already shown it."*  Uncompilable code snippets != MCTaRE.  Please *read* the document rather than make random guesses about what it means.